# How to make Chrome on Android launch my image picker rather than the system UI's in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

My app is a custom image picker written in React Native using Expo, that lets a user select a particular image for uploading. When a user presses an Upload button in any third-part Web page, I want my app to open rather than the standard Android file picker dialog.

Is this possible? I'm only interested in Android at the moment. I've looked at Expo's `ImagePicker`, but this launches the standard Android System UI in response to a call from an app. In contrast, I need *my* app to open, not `ImagePicker`, in response to a user's click on a file upload button in a Web page.

`ContentProviders` looks like a promising approach, but I can't see how to use it in Expo, and I'm not sure if this is the right approach anyway.

`Intents` all seem to load the standard system UI image picker.

Is what I want possible, and if so, what approach should I use to achieve it?